# Дублированная плашка профиля

Tags: дефект, профиль-участника

Зачем нужен этот блок (отображается как минимум на [страницах любых профилей](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current), но не отображается на главной), если он почти такой же, как чуть выше. Отличается только кнопкой "выйти", которая тоже есть рядом - на одну строку ниже.

А вот переходить на мету и другие сайты мешает.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: экспериментируют наверное :) на мете такой нет

Comment: @Grundy, на мете тоже есть.

Comment: у меня пока нет.

Comment: @Grundy проверь по ссылке, у меня есть.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я на странице вопроса проверял :)

Comment: Оказалось, об этом уже есть [бага](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368759/339911).